# Elementwise multiplication of all matrices in a list in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a list of matrices. I need to multiply them together. Normally if we have matrix A and B and need matrix multiplication in R, we use

```
A*B
```

but I can't seem to make * work with lapply in this case. If my list of matrices is called l1 and I use lapply(l1,*) I get an error, and if I use lapply(l1,prod) it gives me the product of all elements within each matrix.

Example:

```
> l1
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    5
[2,]    3    7

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    3    7
[2,]    5    9

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    8
[2,]    1    2
```

Desired output:

```
 l1
      [,1] [,2]
[,1]   30   280
[,2]   15   126
```

Answer (score 5):

`lapply` iterates over a vector/list, but it can only pass one element to a function iteratively. It you want to pass elements iteratively to a binary function (e.g., for a scalar calculate the cumulated product), you can use `Reduce`:

```
Reduce("*", 1:3) == prod(1:3)
#[1] TRUE
```

With your list:

```
l1 <- list(matrix(c(2,3,5,7),2),
           matrix(c(3,5,7,9),2),
           matrix(c(5,1,8,2),2))
Reduce("*", l1)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   30  280
#[2,]   15  126
```